# Installing xmlstarlet on Unix

Tags: xml, unix, installation, xmlstarlet

I downloaded `xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686.rpm` and placed it on Unix box.
When I run `rpm -i xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686.rpm` , I get below errors.

Do I need to install the below libs one by one? Is there any other approach to automatically have these dependencies resolved?

```
warning: xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 81b46521: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libexslt.so.0 is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.0) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.2) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.7) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.8) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.17) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.23) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.8) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxslt.so.1 is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.11) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.18) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.22) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686
        libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.24) is needed by xmlstarlet-1.6.1-6.fc24.i686

$uname
Linux
```

Comment: which linux is it?

Comment: try installing the highest version? `LIBXML2_2.6.23` is the one I see. It's hard to believe they'd require such a hodge-podge of the essentially the same lib. As you haven't had any responses, if you have solved this, please post the answer. You can 'accept' your own answer after 48 hrs and gain additional reputation points. Good luck.